# Unable to save one-to-many relationship objects in to database. How to save a table list?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, service, repository

Question table:

```
public class Question {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        
        @Column
        @NotNull
        private String questionSentence;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        private List<Answers> answers;
        }
```

Answer table:

```
public class Answers {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String answer;
    
    
    
        @ManyToOne 
        @JoinColumn
        @JsonIgnore
        private Question question;
}
```

I would like to save an answer list in Question that I received from a *RequestBody*, but it doesent work:

```
public class QuestionService {
@Autowired
 private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

public ResponseEntity<Question> update
            (Integer questionId,
             Question question) {

Question tempquestion = = questionRepository.findById(questionId);
tempquestion.setAnswers(Question.getAnswers());

 return ResponseEntity.ok(questionRepository.save(tempQuestion));
}
```

The tempQuestion outputs are working(I get a list from all answers), but the "questionRepository.save(tempQuestion)" doesent save it. (If I want to save other things, like String answer sentence or etc it works, but not if I want to save table list.

What could I do wrong?

Comment: Try using cascade = CascadeType.ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to cascade the save operation when the `Question` entity is saved, so use `CascadeType.PERSIST` and `CascadeType.MERGE` on the relationship between `Question` and `Answer` entities:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Answers> answers;
}
```

or if you want to cascade all operations on `Question` down to `Answer` entity, then use:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answers> answers;
}
```